# Disable loopback interface lo0 on 10.8.4?

Tags: network, command-line, performance

For testing purposes (testing raw network speed over a number of cables) i have equippped my Mac Book pro with a Thunderbolt to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter besides the built-in gigabit ethernet connection.

Both interfaces have been assigned a manual IP in the 10.0.*/24 range.

Starting iperf with `iperf -s --bind 10.0.0.1`, then starting the client with `iperf -c 10.0.0.1` yields speeds of over 40 Gigabit per second. I assume (correctly so according to some googling) that not the interface itself is used but rather the local loopback interface as both IPs reside on the same computer. So my thought was to disable `lo0`, even just temporarily by issuing `sudo ifconfig lo0 down`. Thies doesn't work (it might have worked once for a few seconds but I can't prove that). `lo0` just stays up.

Is there a way to (temporarily) disable the local loopback interface `lo0` so I can do my tests?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd suspect that disabling lo0 might have unintended consequences, so it might be better to find another way to accomplish your goal... change the routing tables so 10.0.0.1 doesn't go through lo0, perhaps? I was going to suggest binding the server and client to different interfaces but that didn't make a difference in my test.

Comment: Where do you expect the ethernet packets to flow through once you've disabled `lo0`? From the Thunderbolt adapter to the built-in port?

Comment: @patrix Yes. That way `iperf` would measure the actual throughput the cables can "handle".

Comment: @gabedwrds I rather highly expect disabling `lo0` to have, again, rather bad consequences, but it appeared the only solution. `iperf` knows how to bind to an IP (I`ll edit my request above because I actually used that option), but the kernel seems to outsmart it. One IP belongs to `en0`, the built-in interface, the other to `en3`, the Thunderbolt-to-Gigabit-Ethernet adapter.

Comment: How do you want to force `iperf` to use the two interfaces (one for the server, one for the client)?

Comment: @patrix `iperf` has an `--bind [IP]` option.

Comment: Can't you bind the two calls to `iperf` to the two different interfaces already now and prevent `lo0` from getting used?

Comment: @patrix That's what I was hoping for, but `iperf -c`, ie te client, doesn't have a `--bind` option. My guess is the kernel decides there is a shorter route between those two IPs then using the real interface...

Answer (score 3):

The version of iperf I have (from Homebrew) does indeed allow binding the client and server to different interfaces, like so:

```
iperf -s --bind 10.0.0.1
iperf -c 10.0.0.1 --bind 10.0.0.2
```

(for the purpose of this answer I assume that you want the server on .1 and the client on .2)

The problem is that the routing table (visible through `netstat -rn`) appears to override this, sending traffic to 10.0.0.1 through the loopback interface.

Rather than disabling loopback altogether, you can delete that specific route:

```
sudo route delete 10.0.0.1 127.0.0.1
```

I found that this caused my Mac to be unable to reach itself (on that IP) for a few seconds, until it found an alternate route out the other interface and through my router. Once that route showed up in `netstat -rn`, iperf worked fine. Here's my before and after:

```
[  4] local 192.168.2.99 port 5001 connected with 192.168.2.101 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec  16.7 GBytes  14.3 Gbits/sec
```

And after:

```
[  4] local 192.168.2.99 port 5001 connected with 192.168.2.101 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec   343 MBytes   288 Mbits/sec
```

288Mbps being a fairly reasonable speed considering that one of the interfaces in use is 802.11n wireless.

I was also able to return my routing table to normal by simply toggling the interface off and on again.

Comment: Thanks, a sound idea, except: It doesn't seem to work on my end... Before deleting the route I get `42.5 Gbits/sec`, after deleting the route I get `4.12 Gbits/sec` - regardless of using a simple cable or my handy mini-switch which is only fast ethernet (the connection status correctly shows `100baseT`). And that clearly is not possible.

Comment: That is odd. Does iperf correctly identify the two IPs, just to confirm that both sides are bound to different interfaces? ("local 10.0.0.2 ... connected with 10.0.0.1")? Do you get the same result going both ways (client on 1, server on 2 vs client on 2, server on 1)?

Comment: Yes, the IPs are confirmed and yes, both ways. What's particularly odd is that the "kernel" route gives 40 GBit/sec, this way I get 4 GBit/sec - and the network shouldn't be able to deliver more then 1 GBit/sec or even 100 MBit/sec _at all_... Mysterious ways...